# filter phone number less than 10 numbers in a column -R

Tags: r

I have a database , I am trying to find a identifier with following conditions By taking first 3 letters from first, last 3 letters from last and last 4 digits of Phone1 if Phone1have empty cell we need to take last 4 digits of Phone2.
I want to have only rows with columns have phone1 or phone2 with 10 digits

```
first <- c("apple", "grape", "rose", "Jasmine", "Apricots", "mango", "banana", "Blueberries")
Last <- c("Jackfruit", "Kiwi", "Mulberry", "rabbit ", "pine", "Limes", "", "Nectarine")
Phone1<-c("1234567890", "(456)7089123", "1230789456", "", "999999", " ", "1112223334", "887775")
Phone2<-c("1234737650", "", "15", "8888888888", "99", "3336783245 ", "", "") 
df <- data.frame(first, Last ,Phone1,Phone2)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using what you *showed* (first 3 of `Last`) vice what you *said* (last 3 of `Last`):

```r
phone_coalesce <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  if (!length(dots)) return(character(0))
  dots <- lapply(dots, function(s) gsub("[^0-9]", "", s))
  dots <- lapply(dots, function(s) ifelse(nchar(s) == 10L, s, NA_character_))
  out <- rep(NA_character_, length(dots[[1]]))
  for (dot in dots) {
    isna <- is.na(out)
    if (!any(isna)) break
    out[isna] <- dot[isna]
  }
  out[is.na(out)] <- ""
  substr(out, 7, 10)
}

paste0(substr(df$first, 1, 3),
       substr(df$Last, 1, 3),
       with(df, phone_coalesce(Phone1, Phone2)))
# [1] "appJac7890" "graKiw9123" "rosMul9456" "Jasrab8888" "Aprpin"    
# [6] "manLim3245" "ban3334"    "BluNec"
```

---

Literal code to fill out the templates above.

```r
tempph <- with(df, phone_coalesce(Phone1, Phone2))
tempph
# [1] "7890" "9123" "9456" "8888" ""     "3245" "3334" ""    
df$new <- paste0(substr(df$first, 1, 3), substr(df$Last, 1, 3), tempph)
df[nzchar(tempph),]
#     first      Last       Phone1      Phone2        new
# 1   apple Jackfruit   1234567890  1234737650 appJac7890
# 2   grape      Kiwi (456)7089123             graKiw9123
# 3    rose  Mulberry   1230789456          15 rosMul9456
# 4 Jasmine   rabbit                8888888888 Jasrab8888
# 6   mango     Limes              3336783245  manLim3245
# 7  banana             1112223334                ban3334
```

Comment: I am trying to extract only rows which have 10 digits of phone numbers in the  Phone1 or Phone2 columns @r2evans

Comment: See the edit. Perhaps overly-complicated and/or over-specific.

Comment: – r2evans I want to filter out rows with only  10 digits of phone numbers in the Phone1 or Phone2 column @r2evans

Comment: `df[nzchar(with(df, phone_coalesce(Phone1, Phone2))),]`

Comment: – r2evans_ It does not worked out it is displaying my data frame itself but not mu output@r2evans

Comment: Did you save the output from my `paste0` above, and then save the output from this row filter?

Comment: c<-paste0(substr(df$first, 1, 3),
       substr(df$Last, 1, 3),
       with(df, phone_coalesce(Phone1, Phone2)))
       
       
data<-c[nzchar(with(c, phone_coalesce(Phone1, Phone2))),] I tried this -r2evans

Comment: could you please guide more on this